# Are there any missable classes in Xenoblade Chronicles 3?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

It seems that some optional classes in Xenoblade Chronicles 3 are obtained with the completion of quest lines, or by allies that can join your party.

I am trying to read as little as possible before jumping into this game and during gameplay to avoid spoilers, but also do not want to miss any of these additional classes along the way.

Are any of the optional classes missable? Or, more specifically, are there any that can no longer be obtained after the main story is complete?

Comment: I don't know yet (still working my way through it) but as of now there are no timed missions or anything of the sort. I think they stopped doing missables with XCX, as I can't think of any from 1/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Every class can be obtained at any time during the game. Here are a few details (spoilers tagged; no names are given, just callouts for the story):

- All hero quests that show up randomly (and aren't given to you as a result of the story) stay there permanently, although some may be pushed off due to certain game events, they are not ever missed.
- > At some point, you lose a hero. You have a chance to obtain this hero again later, after certain events. However, you already have this class as it's given to you by the story.
- > There are two post-game classes that you can obtain after killing the final boss.

Comment: Without spoilers, what do you mean quests can be "pushed off"?

Comment: @Stevoisiak some events happen that lock out an area temporarily. You get access to that area again later. Those quests can't be done until you regain access.